# Why when I try to instantiate a class instance, do I get StackOverFlowException?

Tags: c#

I keep getting `StackOverFlowException` whenever I instantiate an instance of A class. I know it has got something to do with the fact that `A.b` field is of type derived from class A. But why would that cause an exception?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     A a = new A(); // exception
}

class A 
{
    private B b = new B();
}

class B:A {}
```

thank you

Comment: because its a highly contrived question ... i thought it was a troll tbh - but i liked the idea of a questions about self referencing that references the website it is on. I cannot think of a real life example where anyone would or be inclined to do this - butt hen that is probalby just a lack of imiagination on my part,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what is happening under the hood

1. Create a new instance of A
2. As a consequence it creates an instance of `B` for the private field `b`
3. `B` derives from `A` and hence has it's own field `b`.  At this point it goes back to step #2 and repeats until a stack overflow occurs

Comment: Since same exception is also thrown if I try to initialize A.b field inside A's constructor, I assume that only way around this is to not initialize A.b field at all?

Answer (score 5):

Because B is inherited from A, each time you're creating an A, a B is created, which, in turn creates another B.  You've essentially created an endless loop of class creation.

Answer (score 1):

Because A has a reference to a class B, which derives from A. Due to constructor chaining, the ctor of B calls the ctor of A, leading to a creation of a new instance of B, which will continue until eternity or a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 1):

Its because constructors are called recursively

Answer (score 1):

Because you ave a circular reference

in order to make a B you have to make an A
In order to Make an A you have to Make an B

As such it tunnels downwards.

To fix it, dont initialise the private field.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your subclass to know about any derivative types, use generics.  This is featured heavily in the CSLA.NET Framework.

```
public class A<T> where T : A<T>
{

}

public class B : A<B>
{

}
```

Note that A doesn't reference B, but you get to encapsulate the derived type at base level on methods etc.

Comment: I've tried instantiating your code, but it doesn't work --> A<A<B>> a = new A<A<B>>();

Comment: Sorry, in all places I use this little pattern the base class is abstract - you instantiate and use B, not A<B>.  I've just tried A<B> b = new A<B>(); where B is derived from A, and this works.  You get only the base class reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of A, it will create an internal instance of B.... which will - guess what - create an internal instance of B which will - guess what - create an internal instance of B which will - guess what - create an internal instance of B.

This is because the B constructor goes on the A constructor which is recursive. Stack overflow.